# HTTP Client Laravel 8 - PUT Request to update doesn't work

Tags: php, httpclient, laravel-8, crud

So, i want to update a data from the API. I use HTTP Client for the connection. POST, GET, DELETE methods are working just fine, except the PUT method. The problem is when i try to update it, the data that i just edited doesn't updated on the table.

I create a view to edit the data, here's my simple form layout on `edit.blade.php` in view folder.

```
<h1>Edit Data Agenda {{ $data['id'] }}</h1>
        <form action="/editAgenda/{{ $data['id'] }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
            <label class="form-label">hari</label>
            <input type="text" name="hari" class="form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock" value="{{ $data['hari'] }}">
            <label class="form-label">tgl</label>
            <input type="text" name="tgl" class="form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock" value="{{ $data['tgl'] }}">
            <label class="form-label">waktu</label>
            <input type="text" name="waktu" class="form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock" value="{{ $data['waktu'] }}">
            <label class="form-label">lokasi</label>
            <input type="text" name="lokasi" class="form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock" value="{{ $data['lokasi'] }}">
            <label class="form-label">kegiatan</label>
            <input type="text" name="kegiatan" class="form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock" value="{{ $data['kegiatan'] }}">
            <label class="form-label">user_id</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_id" class="form-control" aria-describedby="passwordHelpBlock" value="{{ $data['user_id'] }}">
            <button type="submit" class="mt-3 mb-3 btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
        </form>
```

This is get by id function in `AgendaController.php` to show which the data that we will edit.

```
public function getIdAgenda($id)
    {
        $response = Http::withToken('31|14gfAJHaXv6qU3x4WwxAwE8TuTdXVEFbGimMly8S')->get('https://kominfo.kotabogor-api.my.id/Agenda/'.$id);
        return view('edit', ['data' => $response['Agenda']]);
    }
```

And this is the update function in `AgendaController.php`.

```
public function editAgenda(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $response = Http::withToken('31|14gfAJHaXv6qU3x4WwxAwE8TuTdXVEFbGimMly8S')->put('https://kominfo.kotabogor-api.my.id/AgendaUpd/'.$id, [
            'hari' => $request->hari,
            'tgl' => $request->tgl,
            'waktu' => $request->waktu,
            'lokasi' => $request->lokasi,
            'kegiatan' => $request->kegiatan,
            'user_id' => $request->user_id
        ]);

        return redirect('/Agenda');
    }
```

Lastly, here's the route in `web.php`.

```
Route::put('/editAgenda/{id}', [AgendaController::class, 'editAgenda']);
```

If you want to see my full source code adn try it on your own, this is my github link for the project: `https://github.com/decrager/httpclient-crud.git`
Thank you

Comment: You are sending all the information to kominfo.kotabogor-api.my.id right? And your api that sending information is accepting put right? Can you check $response and what is returning? I guess there can be problem with other endpoint. Also, can you check $response->getBody(); and $response->getStatusCode() to check what is returning from the api?